What is dependency in sequential data?
I read from this article,  We know that Whenever the points in the dataset are dependent on the other points in the dataset the data is said to be Sequential data.
A common example of this is a Timeseries such as a weather data.

My question is what does mean the term "dependency"? And in the above example  how data point dependent of one another?

Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/129267/8560, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/648464/2921, https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/45870/1794.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Dependence here means that the value at a particular time is influenced by earlier values.
In case of the data you listed, if the temperature is 35$^o$ for example, it means that neighbouring points leading up to it are likely to be similar. If it is warm now, then it is likely to be warm for the next few points, rather than turning cold all of a sudden.
In other words, earlier points can tell you about what is likely to come next.
The dependence becomes weaker and less relevant for points that are far apart, but it is significant enough for points close together that we would want to exploit it.
